# Putting correct php-code within eval()-string

Tags: php, string, function

I am working on a Wordpress project where I need to dynamically create a function (depending on which kind of template is used for a page or post) that retrieves the comments of each page in question.

So let's say I have pages within Wordpress with the IDs 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150 and out of these 3 are using the template called "blog" (e.g.: 100, 130 and 150).

So in order to retrieve the comments from these 3 pages with AJAX I need to create a function for each of them:

```
function GetComments100() { #### }
function GetComments130() { #### }
function GetComments150() { #### }
```

Here's the function code I need to create individually for each page (and which goes in between the function brackets above (instead of the ####):

```
$defaults = array( 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_id' => $functionID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'count' => false ); 
$comments = get_comments($defaults);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
echo "<div class='table-row' style='margin-bottom:1px'><div class='table-cell-1' style='width:110px;'>".$comment->comment_author.":</div><div class='table-cell-2'style='width:870px;'>".$comment->comment_content."  <em><a>".$comment->comment_date." ... ".get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID)." (".$comment->comment_post_ID.")</a></em></div></div>";
endforeach;
die($results);
```

In order to get the pages I use a loop-function which gives me the page ID as a variable (in my case its $functionID (also included in the array of my function above)).

I have already managed to dynamically create the functions with the following lines of code (I know "eval" is not a good choice but I didn't find any other solution):

```
$string = 'function ' . $functionName . "() { 
####
}";
eval($string);
```

Now instead of the #### I need to integrate the actual function code starting with "$defaults = array(..." but obviously it has to be completely converted to a string - which is what I am struggling with.

Any help would be appreciated (again, I know using "eval" is not nice but so far I didn't find any other solution for this)

Comment: Turn that block of code into `function x($functionID)`. Then change to `function GetComments100() { x(100); }`. Will it work? I don't know a thing about WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using nowdoc for the function body? If you just need expanding $functionName, you can try something like this:

```
      $string="function {$functionName}(){".<<<'END'
$defaults = array( 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_id' => $functionID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'count' => false ); 
$comments = get_comments($defaults);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
echo "<div class='table-row' style='margin-bottom:1px'><div class='table-cell-1' style='width:110px;'>".$comment->comment_author.":</div><div class='table-cell-2'style='width:870px;'>".$comment->comment_content."  <em><a>".$comment->comment_date." ... ".get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID)." (".$comment->comment_post_ID.")</a></em></div></div>";
endforeach;
die($results);
}
END;

eval($string);
```

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the right direction. i've tested it but it didn't work most probably because my php version is prior 5.3... :-( would it work with heredoc as well?

Comment: Yes, but escaping the dollar signs (\$defaults=...), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't use one function per Template with a parameter like this:

```
public function getBlogComments($id){
    //...
}
```

or one function which check the used Template

```
public function getComments($id){
    // get Template of $id
    //...
}
```

Comment: I can't use it that way because I am retrieving the comments from these three (in this example) pages altogether on another single page (incl. a comment form for each of these individual comment-blocks). As I use AJAX to write and retrieve comments I need an individual function for each. I am sure I could combine all three comment sections within one function - but I want them to be treated individually (so - for example - if I write a comment for pageID 130 I only want the comment-block for pageID 130 to be refreshed)